# Size of file goes into GB's on writing some text in it

Tags: java, filewriter

For learning File read and write i have written a method in which i am writing some result into a file.
On running the program the file size goes into GB's and i have to stop the program in between, which i was not expecting.
I am not sure what mistake i am doing.
Can you please point out the mistake in it or better way of doing it.

```
public static void modOperation() {
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    FileWriter fileWriter;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter("Mod.txt");
        while (i > 0) {
            boolean result = ((i-- % 3) == 0);
            fileWriter.write(" result :: " + result);
        }
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: So, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2gb`, and assuming that each character is only 1 byte, which you have 16 of (at the maximum), you do the maths (this doesn't included an OS overhead for managing the file and "assumes" a single byte per character)

Comment: Working as designed. Your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2^31 - 1 which equals `2,147,483,647`.  You are writing the text `" result :: "` plus a number on each line, which is about 20 bytes.

2,147,483,647 x 20 bytes = 42 Terabytes

So your code certainly will cause Gigabytes (and beyond) to be written.

A better solution is to give the loop an upper bound like this:

```
while (i < 100000) {
    boolean result = ((i-- % 3) == 0);
    fileWriter.write(" result :: " + result);
}
```